# Reading and returning multiple bin files

Tags: java

```
    private static int count = 0;

    public static String[] play()throws Exception{
        File file=new File("E:/proj/"+count+".bin");
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("E:/proj/"+count+".bin");

        //reading the byte content of the bin files
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fin.read(fileContent);

        //storing the deserialized object that is returned to an object.
        Object obj=serializer.toObject(fileContent);

        //converting the obtained object to string 
        String word=obj.toString();
        String[] args=new String[]{word};
        count++;
        return args ;          
    }
```

This snippet was actually supposed to read all the bin files present in that specified path and eventually convert it to string and store all the `byte[]` converted to strings as different string elements in a `string[]`  return the `string[]`. Though it reads all the bin files owing to the counter, somehow, it returns only string of the 1st binary file it reads.

Even this modified version dosent seem to work. I guess it reads all the bin files, but returns only the string of the last bin file read. What i was trying out for was, to store all the string elements to the `string[]` and return the `string[]` to another calling function.

```
public static String[] play(){
    int i = 1;
    String[] args=null;;
    String result = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            result += processFile(i++);
            args=new String[]{result}; 
        } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No more files");
            break;
        }
    }  
    return args;
}       

private static String processFile(int fileNumber) throws Exception {
    File file=new File("E:/proj/"+fileNumber+".bin");
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("E:/proj/"+fileNumber+".bin");

    //reading the byte content of the bin files
    byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    fin.read(fileContent);

    //storing the deserialized object that is returned, to an object.
    Object obj=serializer.toObject(fileContent);

    //converting the obtained object to string 
    String word=obj.toString();
    return word;
}
```

Comment: Is the play() method called from within a loop? Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: hii Assylias..the play method is not called from within a loop. It is merely called in another class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement clearly, you may try changing your code this way:

```
    List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (true) {
        try {
            args.add(processFile(i++));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // your code
        }
    }
    String[] array = args.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: @kuki, Don't forget to "accept answer" if it helped you solve the problem else your accept-rate will go down.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the code you just posted:
- result is initialised to null so your code will throw a NPE in the first loop.
- assuming you initialise it properly (in your case to ""), args is reallocated to a new array on each loop so you lose the information you got from the previous loop.

If you want your `play()` method to return an array, where each item in the array is the content of one file, this should work. If you want something different you need to explain your requirement more clearly.

```
public static String[] play() {
    int i = 1;
    List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (true) {
        try {
            files.add(processFile(i++));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No more files");
            break;
        }
    }
    return files.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```